# Get Error While Job executed by SQL JOB AGENT

Tags: sql, ssis, sql-agent-job, sql-agent, sql-server-2019

I am getting below error while execute SSIS Package with SQL Server Agent. I have use administrator account(proxy) to execute this job.

SSIS Package contain data flow task. I have used ODBC connection as data source and OLEDB connection for data destination.

Data Souce :- AS400 JDE system & Data Destination - SQL Server 2019

> SSIS Error Code DTS_E_PRIMEOUTPUTFAILED.  The PrimeOutput method on ODBC Source returned error code 0x80004005.  The component returned a failure code when the pipeline engine called PrimeOutput(). The meaning of the failure code is defined by the component, but the error is fatal and the pipeline stopped executing.There may be error messages posted before this with more information about the failure.End Error  DTExec: The package execution returned DTSER_FAILURE (1)
>   `

Here is the SSIS Log.

[image]

Here the some more details.

•   SQL Edition: 2019 Enterprise
•   OS: Windows 2019 server edition

Issue description:

•   I have SSIS Package which connect to JD Edwards database via ODBC Connection

•   I have Scheduled SQL Job and one of the step is using above package to load data form JD Edwards

•   The job step throw error during execution. Below is the detail description of the error

> Executed as user: {DomainName}{UserName}. Microsoft (R) SQL Server Execute Package Utility  Version 15.0.2000.5 for 32-bit  Copyright (C) 2019 Microsoft. All rights reserved.    Started:  12:39:40 PM  Error: 2020-06-11 12:40:02.18     Code: 0xC0047038     Source: Data Flow Task SSIS.Pipeline     Description: SSIS Error Code DTS_E_PRIMEOUTPUTFAILED.  The PrimeOutput method on ODBC Source returned error code 0x80004005.  The component returned a failure code when the pipeline engine called PrimeOutput(). The meaning of the failure code is defined by the component, but the error is fatal and the pipeline stopped executing.  There may be error messages posted before this with more information about the failure.  End Error  DTExec: The package execution returned DTSER_FAILURE (1).  Started:  12:39:40 PM  Finished: 12:40:02 PM  Elapsed:  21.969 seconds.  The package execution failed.  The step failed.
>   '

Can Anyone Help in this ?

Comment: *"There may be error messages posted before this with more information about the failure"* but you didn't include those prior errors.

Comment: No I have not got any prior errors. This package is ruining in SQL Server 2017 without any issue.

Comment: *"No I have not got any prior errors"* Simply not true. The error is telling you you have prior errors, and you will.

Comment: "The error is telling you you have prior errors" - I am getting this only this error while executing this package thru SQL Agent. If this package run manually using SSDT then i am not getting any error and getting expected data.

Comment: Check the logs in SSISDB, there will be more details, including that error. If you can't give us the actual error, then there's not a lot we can do to help you here; we have no error and no [mre].

Comment: I have added SSIS log.

Answer (score 0):

That log you're looking at must be incomplete.  To get all error messages:

```
USE SSISDB
SELECT * FROM catalog.executions WHERE package_name LIKE 'NameOfYourPackage'
```

Copy the execution_id of the relevant execution (look at dates and times)

```
SELECT * FROM catalog.event_messages WHERE operation_id=[execution_id from previous query] AND message_type>110
```

Comment: Yeah, I have shared above logs from Catalog.Event_Messages.

Comment: That doesn't look like raw output from the catalog.event_messages table.  Reports, for example, don't always show all the events.  Saying that because I've never seen the PRIMEOUTPUTFAILED error without another, more informative error (at almost exactly the same time) also existing.